# Configuring function keys in PuTTY for both Vim and Midnight Commander under tmux?

Tags: vim, keyboard, putty, tmux, midnight-commander

First off, I'm aware that I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (through 9 and 0) to synthesize the respective function keys (<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F10</kbd>) in Midnight Commander. It has helped me many times, but by default I still press the *actual* function keys intuitively.

Gist: I'm trying to run both Vim and Midnight Commander inside a `tmux` session (sometimes window, sometimes pane), using PuTTY.

So by default I have the following PuTTY configuration:

[image: PuTTY keyboard config]

### With `ESC[n~` mapping

The problem now when mapping (`map <F1> :tab help<CR>`, and also `nmap` and `imap`) <kbd>F1</kbd> in Vim, is that it gives the effect of <kbd>~</kbd> (toggle case). And indeed if I press <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F5</kbd> in the shell, the tilde (`~`) is the result, *along* with a bell.
The function keys work perfectly fine in Midnight Commander, though, using this setting.

There is one odd thing about the above setting in addition to my problems with <kbd>F1</kbd>: I also "mapped" <kbd>F5</kbd> (`set pastetoggle=<F5>`) in Vim. Strangely enough *that* works like a charm, even though the <kbd>F5</kbd> key on the shell gives a `~` just like <kbd>F1</kbd> etc.

**Note:** when running Vim outside of `tmux`, the default binding (and my override) of <kbd>F1</kbd> work fine!

### With "Linux" mapping

So naturally I tried to use the "Linux" setting in the dialog above. So when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> Vim goes into insert mode at the end of the line (effect of <kbd>A</kbd>). Midnight Commander doesn't recognize any of the function keys with this setting. Sure enough on the shell <kbd>F1</kbd> gives me `A` and a bell (<kbd>F2</kbd> a `B` and so on).

What am I missing here? **How can I get a uniform behavior where both Midnight Commander and Vim will recognize the function keys?**

---

#### Additional info:

Remote system is Ubuntu 14.04 with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

`TERM` is set to `TERM=xterm` outside the `tmux` session and `TERM=screen` when seen from inside a pane or window.

I am not using:

```
set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

to override the terminal type inside `tmux`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the `TERM=xterm` outside `tmux`.  There is *no* configuration of PuTTY which matches the `xterm` terminal description, and the mismatch feeds into `screen` or `tmux` (take your pick).

See for example, in the ncurses FAQ *[Why not just use TERM set to "xterm"?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_generic)*.  The recommendation there is of course to set

```
TERM=putty
```

A quick check using [`tack`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/tack.html) shows that this combination (`TERM=putty`, `tmux`) works for Ubuntu 14.04 (you should have installed the `ncurses-term` package, which includes this).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I couldn't find `tack` at all, not with `apt-file search` nor after installation of the package you recommended. But `toe -a|grep -i putty` confirms that several PuTTY terminal definitions exist (including a `putty-256color`). I'll try it out and get back to you and also accept accordingly.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that tack wasn't in Ubuntu 14.04 (it's been in Debian a while, but probably overlooked when I split it out of the ncurses source tarball).  Checking my machine, it looks like I was running one of my packages.