# Pressing F7 and above in PUTTY

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm using PUTTY to SSH, and I'm only able to use the function keys up to F6. This is frustrating as F7 is used by the `htop` program. If I type higher than F6 I get the Windows error sound.

How do I enable PUTTY to work with the function keys higher than F6?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/918580/configuring-function-keys-in-putty-for-both-vim-and-midnight-commander-under-tmu

Comment: So basically it's impossible to fix the bug? OK.